# How to prevent HttpRuntime.Cache to remove items in ASP.NET 4.5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, httpruntime.cache, cache-expiration

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092590/how-to-prevent-asp-net-from-removing-items-from-cache), which contains contradictory answers. I am also interested in an answer related to a more recent version of ASP.NET.

My application uses `HttpRuntime.Cache` to cache some lists of models that should never expire. They are loaded on application warmup and they are changed quite rarely, but read quite often.

My code is the following:

```
private void ReportRemovedCallback(string key, object value, CacheItemRemovedReason reason)
{
    if (!ApplicationPoolService.IsShuttingDown())
    {
        var str = $"Removed cached item with key {key} and count {(value as IDictionary)?.Count}, reason {reason}";
        LoggingService.Log(LogLevel.Info, str);
    }
}

private IDictionary<int, T> ThreadSafeCacheAccessAction(Action<IDictionary<int, T>, bool> action = null)
{
    // refresh cache if necessary
    var dict = HttpRuntime.Cache[CacheDictKey] as IDictionary<int, T>;
    bool invalidated = false;
    if (dict == null)
    {
        lock (CacheLockObject)
        {
            // getting expiration times from model attribute
            var cacheInfo = typeof(T).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(UseInCachedRepositoryAttribute), inherit: true).FirstOrDefault() as UseInCachedRepositoryAttribute;
            int absoluteExpiration = cacheInfo?.AbsoluteExpiration ?? Constants.Cache.IndefiniteRetention;
            int slidingExpiration = cacheInfo?.SlidingExpiration ?? Constants.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration;

            dict = _modelRepository.AllNoTracking.ToList().Where(item => item.PkId != 0).ToDictionary(item => item.PkId, item => item);
            HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(CacheDictKey, dict, dependencies: null,
                absoluteExpiration: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(absoluteExpiration),
                slidingExpiration: slidingExpiration <= 0 ? Cache.NoSlidingExpiration : TimeSpan.FromMinutes(slidingExpiration),
                priority: CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable,
                onRemoveCallback: ReportRemovedCallback);

            invalidated = true;
        }
    }
```

Based on the documentation provided [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228248(v=vs.90).aspx), I have also included the following markup within the web.config:

```
<caching>
  <cache disableExpiration="true" disableMemoryCollection="true" />
</caching>
```

However, from time to time, `ReportRemovedCallback` is called for item removal. My feeling is that caching configuration from web.config is ignored (the documentation clearly states it is outdated) and that `CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable` means only "a very high priority", not "never remove".

**Question:** **is there a way to convince HttpRuntime.Cache to never remove some items?** Or should I consider another caching mechanism?

Comment: I always used the good and old static variable, which remains for the life of the AppDomain (e.g until the pool recycles). If you can't use a static variable for some reason, look for @user134706 answer in the question you linked, maybe you can understand what's happening with your case.

Comment: @Alisson - I see no reason for not using a static variable. I already embedded all operations touching `HttpRuntime.Cache` within a critical section, so the replacement should be easy to perform. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I have dug more and there is no definitive answer, but the following configuration from [this old docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228248(v=vs.90).aspx) seems to apply regardless of trials to deny expiration:

> The following default cache element is not explicitly configured in
> the machine configuration file or in the root Web.config file, but is
> the default configuration returned by application in the .NET
> Framework version 2.0.

```
<cache disableMemoryCollection="false" 
  disableExpiration="false" privateBytesLimit="0" 
  percentagePhysicalMemoryUsedLimit="90" 
  privateBytesPollTime="00:02:00" />
```

So, if physical memory usage is above 90%, it will evict cache items. Since OS tends to use almost all physical memory for system cache (reported by Task Manager), this is not so unlikely as it sounds.

### Alternative

I took [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx) for a spin, since it is very similar to `HttpRuntime.Cache`. It provides similar functionality, but lacks the `CacheEntryUpdateCallback` (you can provide it, but complains with InvalidArgumentException if it is different from `null`).

Now my code is the following:

```
var dict = MemoryCache.Default.Get(CacheDictKey) as IDictionary<int, T>;

if (dict == null)
{
    lock (CacheLockObject)
    {
        // getting expiration times from model attribute
        var cacheInfo = typeof(T).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(UseInCachedRepositoryAttribute), inherit: true).FirstOrDefault() as UseInCachedRepositoryAttribute;
        int absoluteExpiration = cacheInfo?.AbsoluteExpiration ?? Constants.Cache.IndefiniteRetention;
        int slidingExpiration = cacheInfo?.SlidingExpiration ?? Constants.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration;
         
        dict = _modelRepository.AllNoTracking.ToList().Where(item => item.PkId != 0).ToDictionary(item => item.PkId, item => item);

        var cacheItemPolicy = new CacheItemPolicy
        {
            AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(absoluteExpiration),
            SlidingExpiration = slidingExpiration <= 0 ? Cache.NoSlidingExpiration : TimeSpan.FromMinutes(slidingExpiration),
            Priority = System.Runtime.Caching.CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable,
            // throws InvalidArgumentException
            // UpdateCallback = CacheEntryUpdateCallback
        };
        MemoryCache.Default.Add(CacheDictKey, dict, cacheItemPolicy);
    }
}
```

After some tests, there were no extra removals and the memory consumption of `w3wp.exe` raised as expected.

More details are provided within [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41820356/2780791).